# Streaming, Asynchronous, Language Independent technology to transfer Object data

Tags: web-services, soap, streaming, soa, data-transfer

**What are the best-practice / industry standard technologies for the folowing requirements**

1. Allow transfer of business objects from one client / server to another
2. Language and platform independent
3. Supports Streaming to alow passing large data (e.g. a connected statefull conversation)
4. Is Asynchronous in nature (doesn't block, allows monitoring progress)

---

**SOAP workaround**

1,2 point on SOAP web services, but 3 and 4 make it a little hard to implement (don't they?)

I was thinking of the following "hack", but I both don't like it, and I'm sure there is a better solution.

To support 3 and 4 the SOAP web service can have methods that pass the data in chunks, e.g.

```
void startObjTransfer(String objectId);
void addObjChunk(String objectId, ObjData currentChunk);
void endObjTransfer(String objectId);
```

Where `ObjData` contains a partial graph of the data, and knowledge of its location in the graph.

to better support 4 a method like this can be used to ask how much progress was made

```
void getObjTransferProgress(String objectId);
```

What do you think about the above? isn't there (hopefully there is) a better one? (even non SOAP)

---

**RMI / COM / .NET Remoting / DCOM**

Not language independed

---

**CORBA**

Well, no.

---

**REST**

Not answering 3 and 4, (SOAP + Buzz?)

---

**AJAX / COMETD**

Related to question: [Asynchronous web service streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769764/asynchronous-web-service-streaming)

Not sure how this will work, please explain

---

**Message Queue?**

Will that work for this purpose?

Comment: Do you mean language independent or platform independent? Using WCF in .NET would be language independent but not platform independent.

Comment: @John - WCF services will run only on .Net but the client can be on any platform written in any language (C#, Java, PHP, Ruby etc.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856368/is-wcf-platform-independent

Comment: @Pavel: I know. That's why I asked which one he meant.

Comment: @Pavel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856368/is-wcf-platform-independent/857825#857825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Coucho [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) should fulfill your needs (including streaming, platform independence...). You might also take a look [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) from the Facebook guys.